# string.replace , python is erasing rest of sentence

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to replace the first World by beautiful in python3 but it's not working as I expected :
My code :

```
string1 = 'Hello World World' # Define my string
name = 'World' # word to replace
val = 'beautiful' # word remplacing the word to replace
print(string1) # printing string before replace
string1 = string1.replace(name, val)
print(string1) # printing string after replace
```

And when I execute it :

BEFORE :

```
Hello World World
```

AFTER :

```
Hello beautiful
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
Hello beautiful World
```

Thanks for any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the max number of replacements.

```
string1 = string1.replace(name, val, 1)
```